# Trying to register for XMPP

Tags: java, android, xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to create an account and then login into my XMPP server.

I have gotten this far:

```
                try {
                    System.out.println("trying to register for XMPP");
                    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                            .setServiceName("jabber.org")
                            .setHost(AppConfig.XMPP_HOST)
                            .setPort(Integer.parseInt(AppConfig.XMPP_PORT))
                            .build();

                    XMPPTCPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
                    connection.connect();
                    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(connection);

                    accountManager.createAccount(name, password);

                    connection.login(name, password);

                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

this is the output:

```
05-17 18:28:12.485  23624-24236/com.example.sqltest2 W/System.err﹕ org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within packet reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s)
05-17 18:28:12.555  23624-24236/com.example.sqltest2 W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkForResponse(SynchronizationPoint.java:192)
05-17 18:28:12.555  23624-24236/com.example.sqltest2 W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkIfSuccessOrWait(SynchronizationPoint.java:114)
05-17 18:28:12.555  23624-24236/com.example.sqltest2 W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkIfSuccessOrWaitOrThrow(SynchronizationPoint.java:97)
05-17 18:28:12.555  23624-24236/com.example.sqltest2 W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:815)
05-17 18:28:12.555  23624-24236/com.example.sqltest2 W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.connect(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:397)
05-17 18:28:12.555  23624-24236/com.example.sqltest2 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.sqltest2.RegisterActivity$4.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:281)
05-17 18:28:12.565  23624-24236/com.example.sqltest2 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.sqltest2.RegisterActivity$4.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:266)
05-17 18:28:12.565  23624-24236/com.example.sqltest2 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-17 18:28:12.565  23624-24236/com.example.sqltest2 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-17 18:28:12.565  23624-24236/com.example.sqltest2 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-17 18:28:12.565  23624-24236/com.example.sqltest2 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-17 18:28:12.565  23624-24236/com.example.sqltest2 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-17 18:28:12.565  23624-24236/com.example.sqltest2 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-17 18:33:07.495  23624-24446/com.example.sqltest2 W/AbstractXMPPConnection﹕ Connection closed with error
    org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException: Parser got END_DOCUMENT event. This could happen e.g. if the server closed the connection without sending a closing stream element
            at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1126)
            at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$200(XMPPTCPConnection.java:915)
            at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:930)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

The error occurs at

```
connection.connect();
```

I am using Ejabberd on linux.

The logs say a succesfull connection was made so I dont really know what is going wrong.

**what could the problem be?**

Comment: You cannot connect to the server, check the address, port and connectivity `05-17 18:28:12.485  23624-24236/com.example.sqltest2 W/System.err﹕ org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within packet reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s)`

Comment: @PedroLobito   Oh really? So the connection was succesful lol.

Comment: "__logs say a successful connection__" , I guess the error message says the opposite, "__No response received within packet reply timeout__". You came to SO searching for help, the least you can do is show some respect for who's trying to help you. I guess your nick says everything, GL solving your problem.

Comment: @PedroLobito   I do respect the help,, what is the reason that you think i am disrespecting you?

Comment: Most likely you 'lol'ing about his comment.

Comment: @Flow          Oh i see,, i was actually only surprised because i misinterpreted the output errors hence the lol (at myself)... it had nothing to do with his comment.

Comment: @PedroLobito   My comment was not meant in a sarcastic way. I was surprised because you said the connection was successful after all. No disrespect meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to check if server supports [In-Band Registration](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html). As far as I know, public registration at jabber.org is [disabled](https://register.jabber.org/) for a long time.

Comment: Thanks, ill check it out shortly!